# not able to save an image file using c?

Tags: c, image-processing, bmp

I tried to clone a bmp image into another bmp image but the final image would not open.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <process.h>

void readBMP(char* filename) {
int i;
FILE* f = fopen(filename, "rb");
FILE* f1= fopen("save.bmp", "wb");
if (!f) {
    printf("Could not read file!\n");
    exit(0);
}
unsigned char info[54];
fread(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, f);
int width  = *(int*)&info[18];
int height = *(int*)&info[22];
printf("%d %d\n", width, height);

fwrite(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, f1);

int length = width * height;
unsigned int image[10000][3];

for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    image[i][2] = getc(f);
    image[i][1] = getc(f);
    image[i][0] = getc(f);

    putc(image[i][2], f1);
    putc(image[i][1], f1);
    putc(image[i][0], f1);

    printf("pixel %d : [%d,%d,%d]\n", i+1, image[i][0], image[i][1], image[i][2]);
}
fclose(f);
fclose(f1);
}
void main() {
char* fileName = "bitgray.bmp";
readBMP(fileName);
getch();
}
```

The image that I took as an input was 114X81 with size of 27918 bytes. 
The final image had same size but the size was 27756 bytes.

What could be the error ??

Comment: How do you know you're getting an error? Is the `fopen()` failing? Is the program crashing? Does a `save.bmp` file appear in your directory but is unreadable?

Comment: length is not as simple as width * height.

Comment: You should check the result of fopen for the file f1.

Answer (score 4):

BMP stores each row in a [multiple of 4 bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Pixel_storage). In your case, that means that each rows takes 116 bytes, (2 bytes padding). That gives 116x78x3+54=27198
 So you are doing it wrong.

BTW the header length not always is 54 bytes.

Comment: But I had read somewhere that a 24 bit bmp image has a header length of 54 and then all the pixel values ...

Comment: For most 24 bit BMP you'll find, that's true. And I guess that's enough for your scenario.

Comment: Should I use `unsigned long int` for getting 4 bytes ? or there could be some other way to get the required padding ?

Comment: What's the problem? Read 116 bytes instead of 114, and that's all.

Comment: BTW, it's rather unusual store the bytes in a matrix and write it again to a file at the same time. BTW2: I'd rather read each full row directly into the matrix in each iteration loop.

Answer (score 1):

BMP images need padding so each line is a multiple of 4 bytes.

Your lines are not a multiple of 4, so you're missing 2 bytes per line, or 162 in total - which is the difference in size.